# Compare arrays with index ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare

I am trying to get the differences between two arrays of equal length in ruby.

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]

array2 = [1,2,4,5]

diffArray = []
diffArray = array1 - array2 # => [3]
```

But I would like to save the index at which the differences occur relative to `array1` or `array2`. For example, I would like `diffArray` to be saved as

`#diffArray => [nil,nil,3,nil]` or `#diffArray => ["","",3,""]`

Is there a way to do this in ruby?

Comment: `array1 - array2 #=> [3]`

Comment: @moveson is not the only one who doesn't understand your question. When you saw his comment and answer you had an obligation to clarify the question, but you didn't. That earns a downvote from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

If you are interested in the *values of* `array1` at the positions at which the values do not match, you might want to use this:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [1,2,4,5]

array1.zip(array2).map { |a, b| a if a != b }
#=> [nil, nil, 3, 4]
```

If you are interested in the *indexes* at which the values do not match (hint: indexes start counting at `0`), try this:

```
array1.zip(array2).map.with_index { |(a, b), i| i if a != b }
#=> [nil, nil, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thank you @spickermann. If possible, can you explain the performance for your answer

Comment: The OP asked for the diff array to contain the indexes of the locations where elements were different. The OP's example is confusing, because the first array is sequential numbers, and in the example given, what is returned happens to equal the last two elements in the first array. @danynl What is it you actually want returned? If you want indexes, shouldn't the example require [nil, nil, 2, 3]?

Comment: @moveson : You are right the question is a bit confusing because the wording and the examples do not really fit together. I updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the OP wants, but if the requirement is an array containing an index, rather than the elements of one of the arrays, then we want:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]
array2 = [1,2,4,5]

(0...array1.size).map { |index| index if array1[index] != array2[index] }
#=> [nil, nil, 2, 3]
```